Shopify / Liquid 304 not modified on GET cart request
Some of our clients are receiving a 304 Not Modified error and cannot look into their shopping cart.
I've tried to look into cart.js or any other associated file but i cannot seem to find the issue.
My collegues and I cannot simulate the problem, so it's an hard find.
I have asked someone to give me the network log and it output:
Request URL:

https://www.kookgigant.nl/cart?section_id=cart-drawer

Request Method:

GET

Status Code:

304 Not Modified

Remote Address:

23.227.38.74:443

Referrer Policy:

strict-origin-when-cross-origin


Alt-Svc:

h3=":443"; ma=86400

Cf-Cache-Status:

DYNAMIC

Cf-Ray:

874b06d33c6e0a74-AMS

Content-Security-Policy:

block-all-mixed-content; frame-ancestors 'none'; upgrade-insecure-requests;

Date:

Mon, 15 Apr 2024 09:49:37 GMT

Etag:

"cacheable:ec2ada8fb77c93f6de98461c96def392"

Nel:

{"success_fraction":0.01,"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}

Powered-By:

Shopify

Report-To:

{"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report\/v4?s=E59gMyI0jCIdcMcZ%2FXjYZv9ubjzJWwYXeNYZ0tZ8%2BS03JVFQQJ%2BLJEGud2f1YY2uDnzaG5pXHOB4Bnl99%2B8WZX6X4ZfrPH0w4v07MwqLR4n9f1%2FFQ7xFxoEbxv8MyUZIroaQ"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}

Server:
cloudflare

Server-Timing:
processing;dur=18;desc="gc:2", db;dur=5, asn;desc="1136", edge;desc="AMS", country;desc="NL", theme;desc="160843006278", pageType;desc="cart", servedBy;desc="9fcd", requestID;desc="0abc3477-f659-4384-baad-7cf539967c6e-1713174577"

Server-Timing:

cfRequestDuration;dur=54.999828, earlyhints

Set-Cookie:

keep_alive=ff8191b8-f1c6-483d-a608-b92115f49889; path=/; expires=Mon, 15 Apr 2024 10:19:37 GMT; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax

Set-Cookie:

secure_customer_sig=; path=/; expires=Tue, 15 Apr 2025 09:49:37 GMT; secure; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax

Set-Cookie:

localization=NL; path=/; expires=Tue, 15 Apr 2025 09:49:37 GMT

Set-Cookie:

cart_currency=EUR; path=/; expires=Mon, 29 Apr 2024 09:49:37 GMT

Set-Cookie:

_cmp_a=%7B%22purposes%22%3A%7B%22p%22%3Atrue%2C%22a%22%3Atrue%2C%22m%22%3Atrue%2C%22t%22%3Atrue%7D%2C%22display_banner%22%3Afalse%2C%22sale_of_data_region%22%3Afalse%7D; domain=kookgigant.nl; path=/; expires=Tue, 16 Apr 2024 09:49:37 GMT; SameSite=Lax

Set-Cookie:

_shopify_y=0e26ef17-a89b-4b43-b0f8-3eee004cd292; Expires=Tue, 15-Apr-25 09:49:37 GMT; Domain=kookgigant.nl; Path=/; SameSite=Lax

Set-Cookie:

_shopify_s=ccb8f765-a174-4195-9050-a89cbe152477; Expires=Mon, 15-Apr-24 10:19:37 GMT; Domain=kookgigant.nl; Path=/; SameSite=Lax

Strict-Transport-Security:

max-age=7889238

Vary:

Accept

X-Cache:

hit, client

X-Content-Type-Options:

nosniff

X-Dc:

gcp-europe-west4,gcp-europe-west3,europe-west3

X-Download-Options:

noopen

X-Envoy-Upstream-Service-Time:

21

X-Frame-Options:

DENY

X-Permitted-Cross-Domain-Policies:

none

X-Request-Id:

0abc3477-f659-4384-baad-7cf539967c6e-1713174577

X-Shardid:

325

X-Shopid:

7304020066

X-Sorting-Hat-Podid:

325

X-Sorting-Hat-Shopid:

7304020066

X-Storefront-Renderer-Rendered:

1

X-Xss-Protection:

1; mode=block

